# Properties about the Generalized Legendre-type polynomial sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(p(x)^n)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose we have the Generalized Legendre-type polynomial sequence $f_n(x)=\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(p(x)^n)$ , where $p(x)$ is any polynomials of degree at least $2$ and has at least two terms.

$1.$ Do these polynomial sequences satisfy any homogeneous linear ODE of polynomial coefficients? Find the one of minimal order if this is the case.

$2.$ Are these polynomial sequences orthogonal, especially when $p(x)$ are polynomials of degree more than $2$ ?

Comment: The first question can be done by induction.

Comment: Does $D(pf_n) = pDf_n + (Dp)f_n$ count?

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer here is a quote from the reference below:


 " 
Suppose the quadratic 
*Ax*<sup>2</sup> + *Bx* + *C* = 0 has distinct real roots *x* = *a* and *x* = *b* . ... when n is a nonnegative integer, it follows that

*y*<sub>*n*</sub> = *K*<sub>*n*</sub>(*d*<sup>*n*</sup>)/(*dx*<sup>*n*</sup>)(*Ax*<sup>2</sup> + *Bx* + *C*)<sup>*n*</sup>





is a solution to

(*Ax*<sup>2</sup> + *Bx* + *C*)*y*’’ + (2*Ax* + *B*)*y*’ − *n*(*n* + 1)*Ay* = 0





Using the usual proof it is easily shown from the differential equation that the *y*<sub>*n*</sub> form an orthogonal set on [*a*, *b*] when *A*, *B* and *C* are independent of n.


" 



A Note on the Derivation of Rodrigues’ Formulae
James M. Horner
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 70, No. 1 (Jan., 1963), pp. 81-82
Published by: Mathematical Association of America
 
Article DOI: 10.2307/2312798
Article Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2312798